# Using delayed job to process a method in background

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, rails-activejob

```
Rails 5.1
```

I have the following in my gemfile

```
gem 'delayed_job'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'daemons'
```

I installed/updated the gems

Then I did:

```
rails generate delayed_job:active_record
```

This generated two files in bin called `delayed_jobs.rb` and created the migration files.

I added the following to `config/application.rb`:

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job
```

I have a controller, with an action, that takes an already uploaded csv file, parses it, and populates the DB with the data. I want that method, or specifically, part of that method to be processed in the background.

The method is:

```
def process_parsed_spreadsheet
  temp_file_path = params[:temp_file_path]
  @spreadsheet   = helpers.open_worksheet(temp_file_path)
  number_of_rows = @spreadsheet.count - 1

  helpers.process_spreadsheet(number_of_rows, @spreadsheet, params[:followed_id])
  helpers.remove_uploaded_file(temp_file_path)

  redirect_to root_path, notice: t('fw_exports.file_successfully_processed')
end
```

I am lost on how to use delayed_jobs to process this method in the background. I read up about having a model, and then having one of the methods in that model process in the background, but this is different.

## Solution (based on the answer below):

I added the following:

app/jobs/parse_and_process_spreadsheet_job.rb

```
class ParseAndProcessSpreadsheetJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(temp_file_path, followed_id)
    @spreadsheet = helpers.open_worksheet(temp_file_path)
    number_of_rows = @spreadsheet.count - 1
    helpers.process_spreadsheet(number_of_rows, @spreadsheet, followed_id)
    helpers.remove_uploaded_file(temp_file_path)
    redirect_to root_path, notice: t('fw_exports.file_successfully_processed')
  end
end
```

And my app/controllers/fw_exports_controller.rb:

```
def process_parsed_spreadsheet
  ParseAndProcessSpreadsheetJob.perform(params[:temp_file_path], params[:followed_id])
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/#queuing-jobs), you should be able to add `handle_asynchronously :process_parsed_spreadsheet` after your class method.

When I've used active_job, I generally create a new file in `app/jobs` e.g. `process_spreadsheet_job.rb` and then create a new class that inherits from `ApplicationJob`. Here's a minimal example:

```
class ProcessSpreadsheetJob < ApplicationJob

    queue_as :default

    def perform(temp_file_path:)
        # Your custom method here.
    end
end
```

Then you can call `ProcessSpreadsheetJob.perform_later()` in your application controller and have a job added to the queue.

Comment: @EastsideDeveloper sorry, it was `perform_later` not `perform` - updated in my answer. You might also refer to this section of the docs about how to enqueue a job: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#enqueue-the-job

Comment: I atm now getting: ActiveJob::SerializationError (Unsupported argument type: ActionController::Parameters) I will check it ou

Comment: Can you try passing the temporary file path in as a string instead of post params? http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/SerializationError.html

Comment: I've done that already. It looks like ActiveJob can't properly serialize the params object. I am now passing two strings as params and it seems to be working fone